# Why did the Ministry remove the dementors from Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

So in *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*

> after Sirius gets freed

The security measures for Hogwarts should stay the same, right? So why did they remove the dementors?

Comment: how did you get a second hnq!

Comment: @Himarm By asking an easy HP question, of course.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Dementors attempting to **Kiss Harry**, was enough to show even Fudge they were not to be trusted at school. Further security is also forgone when Sirius most likely lays a false trail as he says he will.

> ‘He’s not the only one!’ puffed Fudge. ‘The Daily Prophet’s going
>   to have a field day! We had Black cornered and he slipped
>   through our fingers yet again! All it needs now is for the story of
>   that Hippogriff’s escape to get out, and I’ll be a laughing stock!
>   Well ... I’d better go and notify the Ministry ...’
>
> ‘And the Dementors?’ said Dumbledore. ‘They’ll be removed from the
>   school, I trust?’
>
> ‘Oh, yes, they’ll have to go,’ said Fudge, running his fingers dis-
>   tractedly through his hair. ‘Never dreamed they’d attempt to
>   administer the **Kiss on an innocent boy** ... completely out of control
>   ... No, I’ll have them packed off back to Azkaban tonight. Perhaps we
>   should think about dragons at the school entrance ...’ *-Prison of Azkaban*

---

> I believe the Dementors are still searching for me, but they
>   haven’t a hope of finding me here. I am planning to allow some
>   Muggles to glimpse me soon, a long way from Hogwarts, so that
>   the security on the castle will be lifted. *- Prisoner of Azkaban*

Finally we know that later in the series security is never brought back for Sirius due to Kingsley Shacklebolt working with the Order of the Phoenix and Dumbledore to lay a false trail for Sirius.

> Kingsley Shacklebolt’s been a real asset,
>   too; he’s in charge of the hunt for Sirius, so he’s been feeding the
>   Ministry information that Sirius is in Tibet.’

Comment: Those dratted Dementors, trying to take Ginny's job.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - augh!  Did not need that imagery today.

Comment: Not to mention they didn't really work :P

Comment: @Randal'Thor: THWACK! THWACK THWACK THWACK THWACK THWACK!!! And just for good measure, **THWACK!**